# jQuery menu hover off delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, tooltip

I'm using the below jQuery/javascript to control the hover functionality of a menu. When an "item-wrapper" item is hovered over, it display a tooltip submenu.

I wish to add two pieces of functionality to this code:

1) For the Tooltip to only appear after 500milliseconds of hovering over a menu item

2) For the user to be able to move off the tooltip and have it stay visible for about 1 second (thus giving them the option to move back over it before it disappears)

```
$(".item-wrapper").hover(function() {
    $('#' + $(this).attr("rel") + '-tip').fadeIn("fast").show(); //add 'show()'' for IE
},
function() {//hide tooltip when the mouse moves off of the element
$('#' + $(this).attr("rel") + '-tip').hide();
});
```

All help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to delay the call.  The tricky part is making sure to clear the timeouts correctly if the user re-hovers over the element, or hovers over a different one.

```
var timeouts = {};
$(".item-wrapper").hover(function() {
    var rel = $(this).attr("rel");
    var el = $('#' + rel + '-tip');
    if (timeouts[rel]) clearTimeout(timeouts[rel]);
    timeouts[rel] = setTimeout(function () { el.fadeIn("fast").show(); }, 500);
},
function() {
    var rel = $(this).attr("rel");
    var el = $('#' + rel + '-tip');
    if (timeouts[rel]) clearTimeout(timeouts[rel]);
    timeouts[rel] = setTimeout(function () { el.hide() }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: In my example, this doesnt seem to work correctly. When hovering over the menu item, the tooltip no longer appears. The menu items are nested like so:

 <div class="item-wrapper" rel="profile">
  <div id="profile" class="menu-item" onclick="window.location = 'profile.php'"></div>
  <div id="profile-tip" class="tip">
  <div class="tip-header">» Profile</div>
   Content Text
  </div>
 </div>

Comment: @Sam works in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d5NBS/  I was missing one comma between the functions.  Not sure if that's your problem.  If you aren't seeing any js working, check for an error in Chrome developer tools.

Comment: @Sam if this solved your problem, please click the check mark at the top next to the answer.

Comment: David, I marked your answer as correct. However, I have one more request if you'd be happy to oblige. I'd like the script to function so that only the CURRENT tooltip is visible (ie. if I scroll along the menu, that only the current relative tooltip is visible). I'm not very familiar with jQuery but I'm assuming this can perhaps be done by using hide() on all class='tip'?

Comment: @Sam sure, just use $(".tip").hide() to hide all tips instead of just the current one

Comment: @David Fullerton

Sorry mate, where do I pop that in the code? Cheers mate you've been a star!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin. Here's the short description:

> instead of immediately calling the
>   onMouseOver function, it waits until
>   the user's mouse slows down enough
>   before making the call

You can add the 500ms delay before showing the tooltip, but it's not necessary if you're just trying to prevent accidental mouse over. Here's how you may implement it.

```
$(".item-wrapper").hoverIntent({
 over: function() { $('#' + $(this).attr("rel") + '-tip').delay(500).fadeIn("fast").show(); },
 timeout: 1000, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut
 out: function() { $('#' + $(this).attr("rel") + '-tip').hide(); }
});
```

Comment: Looks great, but I do want that delay on the menu popping up (to prevent the user from scrolling across the icons and getting multiple tooltips/submenus pop up). How would I add this delay to the over function?

Comment: @Sam: You can just add `.delay(500)` before `.fadeIn()`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add .delay(500) for the delay before .fadiIn,

Add another delay at the start of the mouseleave function.

Answer (score 0):

How about use jquery delay for the mouseleave, so change it to:

```
function() {//hide tooltip when the mouse moves off of the element
$('#' + $(this).attr("rel") + '-tip').delay(500).hide();
});
```

to delay the hover event is a little more complicated, you need to keep a timer. Something like this:

```
$(function() {
var timer;
$(".item-wrapper").hover(function() {
    if (timer)
    {
       clearTimeout(timer);
       timer=null;
    }
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
       $('#' + $(this).attr("rel") + '-tip').fadeIn("fast").show()
    },500);
});
```

Comment: and I think I missed a }); in there